# Use sudo with .vimrc

Tags: vim, centos

I'm using CentOS and created a `.vimrc` file in my `/home` directory. I tested it out by creating a txt file and yes, that worked fine.  Now, I have my project files in my `/srv` directory with SELinux turned on.  I tried opening a file: `vim README.txt` and yes, my `.vimrc` settings are still being applied.

Now, since I'm in the `/srv` directory, simply doing `vim` means that my file is read only.  So, I do `sudo vim README.txt` in order to be able to edit files.  Now, the problem lies that once I do `sudo`, none of my `.vimrc` settings are applied.  I tried creating a copy of `.vimrc` in the `/srv` folder but that didn't work either.

How do I apply `.vimrc` settings while using `sudo`?

Comment: I would just add a brief explanation: if you execute `sudo`, you switch yourself to the `root` user, so `$HOME` becomes the `/root` directory (unless the `-E` option is used). That means `vim` will load the configuration in `/root/.vimrc`. `vim` is not configured to load the configuration from the current directory by default, that's why it didn't load it from the `/srv` directory.

Comment: Sorry for digging up this old question but maybe it helps someone: For me, `vi` was set as an alias for `vim` for my named-user but not for the root user. No wonder none of the below answers helped; I kept using `vi`.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Use `sudoedit` instead of `sudo vim`.  You should be doing that anyway.  Make sure your `EDITOR` environment variable is set to `vim` (probably already is, or `vim` is the default; you can set it in your `.profile` analog if need be).

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!  One conceptual question: why should I be using `sudoedit` over `sudo vim`?

Comment: @noblerare for security.  Probably doesn't matter for your own system, but it is very important for a system that many users with `sudoers` privileges.  You can run any shell command from `vim`, so with `sudo vim` you could do anything!  `sudoedit` creates a temporary copy of the file and doesn't give such privileges.  `man sudoedit` and `man visudo`

Comment: Also, `$ sudo -e filename`.

Comment: Note that the actual file isn't updated until you exit - not good if you like to save & test your changes without closing vim.

Answer (score 69):

As shown [here](https://coderwall.com/p/xvryda), you can use the following:

```
sudo -E vim README.txt
```

From the man page:

```
-E    The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The
  security policy may return an error if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.
```

The accepted answer is the most secure. But this one is more flexible as I can use `sudo -E operation` with any operation, I don't have to configure anything else beforehand.

Comment: @Claudio do you have any more details than that, as to your specific setup? `sudo -E *` should work for any command. Are you sure the .vimrc you want to use is set for the currently running user that you're logged into? Are you sure you didn't accidentally switch to another user and using their .vimrc or lack of one, instead of the one you want to use?

Comment: Tried again. OS: CentOS 7. If I run `vim *` `.vimrc` is loaded. If I run `sudoedit` it is loaded too. But if I run `sudo -E vim *` it doesn't.

Comment: @Claudio What is the * for? I'm not saying you shouldn't use it, I just don't know what it is for. Also, I use `sudo -E vim` without the * and that works for me.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 I thought he meant whatever file he was trying to edit (replace * with the filename), I assumed he didn't actually type that. Good question.

Comment: this solution also gives you flexibility to use extensions such as CTRL+P, unlike the sudoedit solution

Comment: Indeed the most practical answer. `sudoedit` is good when on a server, but its security when editing my home machine's configs is a bit over the top.

Answer (score 22):

/root/.vimrc is the working directory of sudo vim.

You need copy your .vimrc file from **/home/ec2-user/.vimrc** to **/root/.vimrc**

Comment: the only true answer here

Answer (score 3):

The presented solutions in the other responses work but are not very practical, as you have to enter you password every time you want to edit a file.

I usually have a `tmux` session open within which I am rooted via `sudo su`, so I enter my password once at the beginning of the session and can then work for hours without having to enter it again.

I worked around the issue presented here by creating the following symbolic links : 

`sudo su
ln -s /home/MY-USER-NAME/.vimrc .vimrc
ln -s /home/MY-USER-NAME/.vim .vim`

You might need to remove the `/root/.vim/` directory first.

I hope this helps

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you don't need `sudo` for `su`. Just `su` and enter your password. If you want the benefits of a superuser tmux session (i.e. avoid typing the password repeatedly), while also keeping your normal user environment, and without having to create symlinks in the root home directory, use `sudo -E` when you start your tmux session, as suggested by one of the previous answers: `sudo -E tmux new -s foo`.